# Apache ignite. QueryCursor work without transaction mode even transaction if directly declare. Why?

Tags: java, transactions, ignite

QueryCursor work without transaction mode even transaction if directly declare.

I use [get](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#get-K-) and [put](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#put-K-V-) methods and directly declare transaction. It works normal, i.e.:

```
Ignite ignite = ...;
IgniteCache<String, String> cache = ...;
String key = ...;
String val= ...;
try (Transaction tx = ignite.transactions().txStart()) {
    //get and put work within transaction
    cache.get(key);
    cache.put(key, val);
    tx.commit();
    }
```

But when I use [query](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#query-org.apache.ignite.cache.query.Query-) this works without transaction, i.e.

```
Ignite ignite = ...;
IgniteCache<String, String> cache = ...;
ScanQuery<String, String> query = ...;
try (Transaction tx = ignite.transactions().txStart()) {
    try (QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<String, String>> cursor = cache.query(query)) {
        //query works without transaction 
        Iterator<Cache.Entry<String, String>> iter = cursor.iterator();
        Cache.Entry<String, String> entry = iter.next();
        }
     tx.commit();
}
```

How bind **QueryCursor** to transaction?

Answer (score 2):

To make queries transactional, [TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.7.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/CacheAtomicityMode.html#TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT) cache atomicity mode should be used. It's available since Ignite 2.7.

See: https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.7/docs/multiversion-concurrency-control